# How to create Glue connection to a rds instance running in different region VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc, aws-glue, aws-regions

Our database which we want to crawl is in us-west-1 region and glue service is not yet available in this region. So I am using glue in us-west-2, Now I want to create a connection to database in us-west-1 region.

While creating the connection, It asks for the VPC in which datastore is located and lists all available VPC for that region. But my database is in different region's VPC so its not there in dropdown list to select from. Any idea how to fix this?

> VPC Choose the name of the virtual private cloud (VPC) that contains
>   your data store. The AWS Glue console lists all VPCs for the current
>   region.

Comment: Aashish, have you figured out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did use pymysql / MySQLDB library, and configured the RDS URL directly within my code.  Did you try that?

Sample:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb

dbconn = MySQLdb.connect("URL", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE")
cursor = dbconn.cursor()
cursor.execute("YOUR QUERY GOES HERE")
cursor.fetchall()
dbconn.commit()

dbconn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, my use case is to create a glue connection which will be used by Glue Crawler for crawling RDS database and populate glue catalog. For this, I cannot use the above code as I am not using Glue ETL job.

Comment: Yuva, Where do you run this code, in Glue's ETL script part? where do you define the VPC, subnet, etc. of the glue? if you do not define it somewhere in glue, the connection from glue will be blocked by the security group of the RDS (I assume the security group of the RDS does not simply allow All Traffic). Thanks,